# Interpreting a function

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

I must come up with a  function that evaluates an abstract syntax tree and returns the result of its evaluation.

evaluate will have type Exp -> int option

> evaluate (Prod(Num 5, Diff(Num 6, Num 1)));;
>    val it : int option = Some 25

@John Palmer
How do i go about doing this? Can I use pattern matching? if so how would I do it in order to identify the operation that needs to be done.

Here is what i have come up with? I still dont understand the code per say.

```
let rec evaluate = function
 | Num n -> Some n
 | Neg e -> match evaluate e with
 |Sum (a,b) -> evaluate(a) + evaluate(b)
 |Diff(a,b) -> evaluate(a) - evaluate(b)
 | Prod (a,b) -> evaluate(a) * evaluate (b) 
 |Quot (a,b) -> evaluate(a) / evaluate(b)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some hints to get started

```
let rec evaluate AST =
   match AST with
   |Prod(a,b) -> evaluate(a) * evaluate(b)
   |Num(a) -> a
   ....
```

**EDIT**

So I assume your data type looks like

```
type AST =
|Num of int
|Neg of AST
|Prod of AST * AST
|Diff of AST * AST
|Quot of AST * AST
|Sum of AST * AST
```

so you set up your AST (presumably you are parsing this from somewhere - which is a whole other question) with something like

```
let ast = Prod(Num 5, Diff(Num 6, Num 1))
```

then you can define evaluate as

```
let rec evaluate arg =
    match arg with
    |Num n -> n
    |Neg tree -> - (evaluate tree)
    |Sum (a,b) -> (evaluate a) + (evaluate b)
    |Prod(a,b) -> (evaluate a) * (evaluate b)
    |Quot(a,b) -> (evaluate a) * (evaluate b)
    |Diff(a,b) -> (evaluate a) - (evaluate b)
```

then call it and print the result with

```
printfn "%i" (evaluate ast)
```

Note that `evaluate` has to have type `AST -> int` as otherwise you will need to handle option cases - for example what is `2 * None` or `2 + None`

I am not sure what you mean by

> how should i go about calling the recursive method on smaller inputs.

but hopefully this explains everything

Comment: `evaluate` needs to be recursive, i.e. `let rec evaluate ...`

Comment: Okay I got it to work with ints , but I am supposed to return Some int. Now, when I do  |Num n ->  Some n                                     I get ~vs3783.fsx(118,34): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    int option    
but here has type
    Exp    
>

Comment: @user1072706 - as i said in the post, you will have to deal with `2 + None` if you use options.  The operators `+,*,/` aren't defined for `int Option` only `int`

Answer (score 2):

Start by looking into grammars, lexers, and parsers to generate your AST for you.  Once you have that, it's a simple matter of walking the tree and evaluating it.

Here's a link to one for F#:

http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/

Comment: Sounds like they already have an AST and just want to evaluate it.

Answer (score 2):

I published a little interpreter written in OCaml for a tiny functional language [here](http://www.ffconsultancy.com/ocaml/benefits/interpreter.html). Note the `eval` function in particular. Your problem is simpler because you don't have variables so you don't need the `vars` dictionary I had and you're always returning `int` results so you don't need the `value` union type.

To evaluate an integer expression you just evaluate the subexpressions and do something simple with them. This is most elegantly written as a pattern match:

```
type Expr =
  | Int of int
  | Neg of Expr
  | Add of Expr * Expr
  | Mul of Expr * Expr

let rec eval = function
  | Int n -> n
  | Neg f -> -eval f
  | Add(f, g) -> eval f + eval g
  | Mul(f, g) -> eval f * eval g
```

For example:

```
Mul(Int 2, Neg(Int 3)) |> eval
```

The advantage of pattern matching is that you can add more complicated actions based upon the contents and shape of the data structure. For example:

```
| Add(f, Neg g) -> eval f - eval g
```

Before you know it you're doing [computer algebra](http://fsharpnews.blogspot.com/2007/02/symbolic-manipulation.html).